# retornando dados no Array_filter

Tags: php

Amigos, no código abaixo faço o seguinte:

```
$term = '422';

$data = json_decode($response);
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($term) {
   return stripos($item->id, $term) !== false;
});

print_r($filtered);
```

E tenho então este retorno abaixo:

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 422 [filial] => 4 [name] => 
 COD. 069 30 Mb TRANSPORTE [nome_amigavel] => 30 Mb [mensalidade] => 
 1500.00 [desconto] => 0.00 [ativo] => 1 [tipo] => 3 [instalacao] => 
 1500.00 [bnd_up] => 0 [bnd_down] => 30000 ) )
```

Como eu faria para Tirar desse retorno com um echo ou print somente UMA informação !?  exemplo :  30 Mb

Comment: $filtered[0]->nome_amigavel

Comment: rs.  Simples ,  Obrigado Felipe !!!!

Comment: Teria como pegar de outra forma sem ser pelo numero do array [0] ! ?

Comment: Usando [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.reset.php): `reset($filtered)->nome_amigavel`

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo,  funcionou direitinho !!!!